# Compound with two functional group

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, alcohols, structural-formula

Compound X has 3 carbon atoms in one molecule. It contains a primary alcohol and a carboxylic acid functional group.

Draw the displayed formula of Compound X.

Help! Condensed formula is fine for me!

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!  This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Draw a chain of **three** carbon atoms.
2. Make one of them $\ce{COOH}$. You have **two** carbon atoms to choose from.
3. Attach $\ce{OH}$ to one of the remaining carbon atoms to make it a primary alcohol. You have **one** carbon atom to choose from.

Comment: So I have OH on one end and COOH on the other end, am I correct?
OH-CH2CH2-COOH

Comment: @Benedict Based on your description, I came to the same conclusion :) We learn: If in doubt, draw structures! If you found my hints helpful, please mark my answer as accepted. Btw, welcome to Chemistry.SE!

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask one more thing. Is it possible for Compound X to go through self-polymerization? A condensation polymerization?

Comment: @Benedict Yes :) You're right, the condensation will form chains with a repeating ester motive.